# Segmentation fault for AES 192, AES-256 , not for AES-128 bit

Tags: c, openssl, cryptography, performance-testing

I am trying to decrypt ciphertext using openssl's AES_decrypt function with different key sizes. I am successfully able to decrypt messages with key size = 128.
Here is my code

mydecrypt.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "AES.h"
#include "string.h"
#include "stdlib.h"

#define NO_OF_DECRYPTION 50

static const unsigned char key[]={
0x8E,0xa1,0xeE,0xce,0x5F,0xEB,0x1E,0x8d,0xa5,0xdA,0x95,0x57,0xD0,0x77,0xee,0xd8,0x49,0xfc,0xBd,0x2d,0x0D,0xF0,0x40,0x35,0xd3,0xd8,0x07,0x8f,0xce,0xFD,0x24,0xaF
};     

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    unsigned char *text = (unsigned char *)malloc(16*sizeof(char));;
    unsigned char out[20]; 
    unsigned char * input = (unsigned char *)malloc(NO_OF_DECRYPTION*16*sizeof(char)); 

    FILE *myfile;
    myfile = fopen("encrypted.bin", "r");
    fread(input, sizeof(char), NO_OF_DECRYPTION*16, myfile);

    AES_KEY wctx;
    int aes_counter=0;
    private_AES_set_decrypt_key(key, 128, &wctx);   // keysize = 192, 256 causes segmentation fault
    printf("AES Decryption started\n");     

    while(aes_counter<NO_OF_DECRYPTION)
    {
        text = &input[aes_counter*16];
        AES_decrypt(text, out, &wctx);
        aes_counter++;
    }
    printf("AES Decryption finished\n");        
    fclose(myfile);

return 0;
}
```

I have copied aes_core.c (renamed as AES.c), aes.h (renamed as AES.h) of openssl files and created my own shared library to run the above code.

//AES.h

```
#include <stdint.h>

#ifndef AES_h__
#define AES_h__

typedef uint8_t     u8;
typedef uint16_t    u16;
typedef uint32_t    u32;

struct aes_key_st {
    unsigned int rd_key[4 *(10 + 1)];
    int rounds;
};
typedef struct aes_key_st AES_KEY;

extern int private_AES_set_decrypt_key(const unsigned char *userKey, const int bits,AES_KEY *key);
extern void AES_decrypt(const unsigned char *in, unsigned char *out,const AES_KEY *key);

#endif  // foo_h__
```

Here is how I have compiled my code to run successfully for keysize=128 bit.

```
gcc -c -Wall -Werror -fPIC -O0 AES.c
gcc -shared -o libAES.so AES.o
var=`pwd`
gcc -std=gnu89 -g -L$var -O0 -Wall -o dec mydecrypt.c -lAES -fPIC
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$var:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$var:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
#run 
./dec
```

Although I am able to encrypt plaintext and decrypt ciphertext using AES_key with key_size=128,  **however I am getting segmentation fault for other key size 192 and 256.**.

`private_AES_set_decrypt_key(key, 192, &wctx);` **is not generating segmentation fault**

however,  `private_AES_set_decrypt_key(key, 256, &wctx);` **is generating segmentation fault**

For both key-size=192 and key-size=256, 
`AES_decrypt()` **is generating segmentation fault**

What is the reason for segmentation fault with key-size 192 and 256 ?

Where I am making mistakes?

Any suggestion/clue to run the code to decrypt using key-size=192/256 will be great help.

I am using gcc-4.9.2 in Debian 8 . Thanks in advance.

Note:
**For encryption, with key-size=128**

```
AES_set_encrypt_key((const unsigned char *)key, 128, &enc_key);
```

**doesn't cause any segmentation fault , however**

```
AES_set_encrypt_key((const unsigned char *)key, 192, &enc_key);
AES_set_encrypt_key((const unsigned char *)key, 256, &enc_key);
```

**both causes  segmentation fault.**

part of AES.c where private_AES_set_decrypt_key and private_AES_set_encrypt_key are defined

```
/**
 * Expand the cipher key into the encryption key schedule.
 */
int private_AES_set_encrypt_key(const unsigned char *userKey, const int bits,
                                AES_KEY *key)
{
    u32 *rk;
    int i = 0;
    u32 temp;

    if (!userKey || !key)
        return -1;
    if (bits != 128 && bits != 192 && bits != 256)
        return -2;

    rk = key->rd_key;

    if (bits==128)
        key->rounds = 10;
    else if (bits==192)
        key->rounds = 12;
    else
        key->rounds = 14;

    rk[0] = GETU32(userKey     );
    rk[1] = GETU32(userKey +  4);
    rk[2] = GETU32(userKey +  8);
    rk[3] = GETU32(userKey + 12);
    if (bits == 128) {
        while (1) {
            temp  = rk[3];
            rk[4] = rk[0] ^
                ((u32)Te4[(temp >> 16) & 0xff] << 24) ^
                ((u32)Te4[(temp >>  8) & 0xff] << 16) ^
                ((u32)Te4[(temp      ) & 0xff] << 8) ^
                ((u32)Te4[(temp >> 24)       ]) ^
                rcon[i];
            rk[5] = rk[1] ^ rk[4];
            rk[6] = rk[2] ^ rk[5];
            rk[7] = rk[3] ^ rk[6];
            if (++i == 10) {
                return 0;
            }
            rk += 4;
        }
    }
    rk[4] = GETU32(userKey + 16);
    rk[5] = GETU32(userKey + 20);
    if (bits == 192) {
        while (1) {
            temp = rk[ 5];
            rk[ 6] = rk[ 0] ^
                ((u32)Te4[(temp >> 16) & 0xff] << 24) ^
                ((u32)Te4[(temp >>  8) & 0xff] << 16) ^
                ((u32)Te4[(temp      ) & 0xff] << 8) ^
                ((u32)Te4[(temp >> 24)       ]) ^
                rcon[i];
            rk[ 7] = rk[ 1] ^ rk[ 6];
            rk[ 8] = rk[ 2] ^ rk[ 7];
            rk[ 9] = rk[ 3] ^ rk[ 8];
            if (++i == 8) {
                return 0;
            }
            rk[10] = rk[ 4] ^ rk[ 9];
            rk[11] = rk[ 5] ^ rk[10];
            rk += 6;
        }
    }
    rk[6] = GETU32(userKey + 24);
    rk[7] = GETU32(userKey + 28);
    if (bits == 256) {
        while (1) {
            temp = rk[ 7];
            rk[ 8] = rk[ 0] ^
                ((u32)Te4[(temp >> 16) & 0xff] << 24) ^
                ((u32)Te4[(temp >>  8) & 0xff] << 16) ^
                ((u32)Te4[(temp      ) & 0xff] << 8) ^
                ((u32)Te4[(temp >> 24)       ]) ^
                rcon[i];
            rk[ 9] = rk[ 1] ^ rk[ 8];
            rk[10] = rk[ 2] ^ rk[ 9];
            rk[11] = rk[ 3] ^ rk[10];
            if (++i == 7) {
                return 0;
            }
            temp = rk[11];
            rk[12] = rk[ 4] ^
                ((u32)Te4[(temp >> 24)       ] << 24) ^
                ((u32)Te4[(temp >> 16) & 0xff] << 16) ^
                ((u32)Te4[(temp >>  8) & 0xff] << 8) ^
                ((u32)Te4[(temp      ) & 0xff]);
            rk[13] = rk[ 5] ^ rk[12];
            rk[14] = rk[ 6] ^ rk[13];
            rk[15] = rk[ 7] ^ rk[14];

            rk += 8;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}

/**
 * Expand the cipher key into the decryption key schedule.
 */
int private_AES_set_decrypt_key(const unsigned char *userKey, const int bits,
                                AES_KEY *key)
{

    u32 *rk;
    int i, j, status;
    u32 temp;

    /* first, start with an encryption schedule */
    status = private_AES_set_encrypt_key(userKey, bits, key);
    if (status < 0)
        return status;

    rk = key->rd_key;

    /* invert the order of the round keys: */
    for (i = 0, j = 4*(key->rounds); i < j; i += 4, j -= 4) {
        temp = rk[i    ]; rk[i    ] = rk[j    ]; rk[j    ] = temp;
        temp = rk[i + 1]; rk[i + 1] = rk[j + 1]; rk[j + 1] = temp;
        temp = rk[i + 2]; rk[i + 2] = rk[j + 2]; rk[j + 2] = temp;
        temp = rk[i + 3]; rk[i + 3] = rk[j + 3]; rk[j + 3] = temp;
    }
    /* apply the inverse MixColumn transform to all round keys but the first and the last: */
    for (i = 1; i < (key->rounds); i++) {
        rk += 4;
        for (j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
            u32 tp1, tp2, tp4, tp8, tp9, tpb, tpd, tpe, m;

            tp1 = rk[j];
            m = tp1 & 0x80808080;
            tp2 = ((tp1 & 0x7f7f7f7f) << 1) ^
                ((m - (m >> 7)) & 0x1b1b1b1b);
            m = tp2 & 0x80808080;
            tp4 = ((tp2 & 0x7f7f7f7f) << 1) ^
                ((m - (m >> 7)) & 0x1b1b1b1b);
            m = tp4 & 0x80808080;
            tp8 = ((tp4 & 0x7f7f7f7f) << 1) ^
                ((m - (m >> 7)) & 0x1b1b1b1b);
            tp9 = tp8 ^ tp1;
            tpb = tp9 ^ tp2;
            tpd = tp9 ^ tp4;
            tpe = tp8 ^ tp4 ^ tp2;
#if defined(ROTATE)
            rk[j] = tpe ^ ROTATE(tpd,16) ^
                ROTATE(tp9,24) ^ ROTATE(tpb,8);
#else
            rk[j] = tpe ^ (tpd >> 16) ^ (tpd << 16) ^ 
                (tp9 >> 8) ^ (tp9 << 24) ^
                (tpb >> 24) ^ (tpb << 8);
#endif
        }
    }
    return 0;
}

#endif /* AES_ASM */
```

Segmentation occurs while calling this two function with key-size=192 and 256. Although inside these two functions it is clearly assign no of rounds with respect to key-size ( key-size=128, total_round=10,key-size=192, total_round=12,key-size=256, total_round=14), still segmentation faults occurs at these two functions.

Comment: Why are you looping on `NO_OF_DECRYPTION`?

Comment: @zaph I need to perform 50 decryptions.

Comment: @zaph I have used AES_set_encrypt_key((const unsigned char *)key, 128, &enc_key); for key-size=128, and AES_encrypt(text, enc_out, &enc_key); to encrypt the text. However, AES_set_encrypt_key((const unsigned char *)key, 192, &enc_key); and AES_set_encrypt_key((const unsigned char *)key, 256, &enc_key); both causes segmentation fault.

Comment: With key-size= 192 and 256, segmentation fault occurs at AES_set_encrypt_key((const unsigned char *)key, 256, &enc_key); means encryptions not started.

Comment: code for AES_encrypt and AES_decrypt is declared in aes_core.c ( in my case it is AES.c).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ignore my previous incorrect answer attempt.

The `rd_key` field of `AES_KEY` is an `unsigned int` array with 44 elements.

The `rounds` field can be initialized with values of 12 (for 192 bit keys) or 14 (for 256 bit keys).

The `rounds` field is then used as a limit on the index into the `rd_key` array (through the `rk` pointer), and the index can go beyond the end of the array. In `private_AES_set_decrypt_key()` there is this snippet of code:

```
/* invert the order of the round keys: */
for (i = 0, j = 4*(key->rounds); i < j; i += 4, j -= 4) {
    temp = rk[i    ]; rk[i    ] = rk[j    ]; rk[j    ] = temp;
    temp = rk[i + 1]; rk[i + 1] = rk[j + 1]; rk[j + 1] = temp;
    temp = rk[i + 2]; rk[i + 2] = rk[j + 2]; rk[j + 2] = temp;
    temp = rk[i + 3]; rk[i + 3] = rk[j + 3]; rk[j + 3] = temp;
}
```

When `rounds` is 12, `j` will start at 48, so all of the accesses using the `j` variable in the first two loop iterations above are beyond the end of the array.  It's a bit worse when the 256 bit key uses 14 rounds.  Since some of those accesses are writes, the `rounds` field will get overwritten as well, and at that point who know what'll happen to the `rd-key` array since `rounds` gets used as a limit in the following loop?

Other loops move the `rk` pointer beyond the start of the `rd_key` array, so it's difficult to know if they access beyond the end of the array, but should be able to verify whether or not that's happening using a debugger.

Perhaps all you need to do is change the definition of `struct aes_key_st` to:

```
struct aes_key_st {
    unsigned int rd_key[4 *(14 + 1)];
    int rounds;
};
```

to accommodate up to the 14 `rounds` of 256 bit keys.

Comment: thank you so much. The above solution solves my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Do not use the block level encryption code, you need to use a level that supports input larger that a block so looping is not required, modes such as CBC and padding such as PKCS#7

Comment: There are examples on SO that are "C" based. It is very uncommon the use block level encryption. With block level you will have to do your own padding for input that is not a block-size multiple. The mode will essentially be ECB mode which is not secure, see [ECB Mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_mode_of_operation#Electronic_Codebook_.28ECB.29), scroll down to the Penguin.

Comment: I agree with you that I need to do the padding in case of input is not multiple of block-size. As of now, I am passing input of length of multiple of block-size ( hardcoded ), and trying to use block level encryption. I think by default CBC is implemented and in that case how to solve this segmentation fault with key-size=192 and 256 ?